# 403 when attempting to use ajax to POST to the apps directory in Magento; only on 1 of 4 servers

Tags: php, ajax, apache, magento, post

I wrote a very simple Magento module that sends an email but doesn't use Magento's core emailing system. I'm using ajax to POST to email.php

I've tested this to oblivion in three separate environments: local, development, and staging. It works flawlessly on all three.

Now when I took these changes live on a fourth server, all post requests return the following:

```
POST http://mydomain.com/dir/path/email.php 403 (Forbidden)
```

And all post requests log the following to my error log:

```
client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/dir/path/email.php, referer: http://mydomain.com/myCategory/myProduct
```

Everything appears to be exactly the same between the four servers. I've checked permissions and httpd.config as well as .htaccess files.

I can add the following to the /apps/.htaccess to get everything to work on live, however I can't keep it this way for obvious reasons.

```
<Limit POST>
order deny,allow 
deny from all 
allow from all
</Limit>
```

I thought there was a possibility that the magneto root .htaccess file could be the culprit but the staging and dev servers are clones of the live site.

Basically, I've checked everything I can think of on the server side of things. I'm completely perplexed as to why my module would work on three separate servers but not on the live site. Is there anything file related that could be causing this? Maybe firewall rules? The generic error in my log file is making this difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: Apache 2.2 or Apache 2.4?

Comment: I usually throw a few sanity checks at things — can you access the file if you rename it?  Move it somewhere else?  Make it print out a simple "Hello World" message instead of sending the email?

Comment: I tried all of the above to no avail. I was able to get it to respond without the vulnerability by using limit post on the file. I still feel this is more of a work-around than a solution.

Comment: Already checked against http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration?